# CPT, Custom User Role and problem with user manager

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles

i've create a custom user role using this code:

```
    /* aggiungi ruolo */
add_role('brokers', 'Brokers', array(
'read' => true, // True allows that capability
'edit_pages' => true,
'edit_others_pages' => true,
'edit_published_pages' => true,
'publish_pages' => true,
));
```

Then i've create two CPT using this code

```
// Sinistri
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_sinistri' );
function register_cpt_sinistri() {
$labels = array( 
    'name' => _x( 'Sinistri', 'sinistri' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Sinistro', 'sinistri' ),
    'add_new' => _x( 'Aggiungi Sinistro', 'sinistri' ),
    'add_new_item' => _x( 'Aggiungi Nuovo Sinistro', 'sinistri' ),
    'edit_item' => _x( 'Modifica Sinistro', 'sinistri' ),
    'new_item' => _x( 'Nuovo Sinistro', 'sinistri' ),
    'view_item' => _x( 'Guarda Sinistro', 'sinistri' ),
    'search_items' => _x( 'Cerca Sinistri', 'sinistri' ),
    'not_found' => _x( 'Nessun Sinistro Trovato', 'sinistri' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'Sinistri non trovati', 'sinistri' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Sinistro:', 'sinistri' ),
    'menu_name' => _x( 'Gestione Sinistri', 'gallery' ),
);
$args = array( 
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'description' => 'Image galleries for teachers classes',
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author'),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'has_archive' => false,
    'query_var' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'capabilities' => array(
        'edit_post' => 'edit_sinistri',
        'edit_posts' => 'edit_sinistris',
        'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_other_sinistris',
        'publish_posts' => 'publish_sinistris',
        'read_post' => 'read_sinistri',
        'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_sinistris',
        'delete_post' => 'delete_sinistri'
    ),
    // as pointed out by iEmanuele, adding map_meta_cap will map the meta correctly 
    'map_meta_cap' => true
);
register_post_type( 'sinistri', $args );
flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

and this code:

```
//Area Clienti Riservata
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_area_clienti' );
function register_cpt_area_clienti() {
    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( 'Area Clienti', 'area_clienti' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Area Clienti', 'area_clienti' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'area_clienti' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New Area Clienti', 'area_clienti' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Area Clienti', 'area_clienti' ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'New Area Clienti', 'area_clienti' ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'View Area Clienti', 'area_clienti' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search Area Clienti', 'area_clienti' ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'No area clienti found', 'area_clienti' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No area clienti found in Trash', 'area_clienti' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Area Clienti:', 'area_clienti' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Area Clienti', 'area_clienti' ),
    );
    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'description' => 'Gestione clienti agenzia assicurativa',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor' ),

        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,

        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'has_archive' => false,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capabilities' => array(
        'edit_post' => 'edit_sinistri',
        'edit_posts' => 'edit_sinistris',
        'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_other_sinistris',
        'publish_posts' => 'publish_sinistris',
        'read_post' => 'read_sinistri',
        'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_sinistris',
        'delete_post' => 'delete_sinistri'
    ),
    );
    register_post_type( 'area_clienti', $args );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

Then i've setting the user role with this code:

```
function add_theme_caps() {
    // gets the administrator role
    $roles = get_role( 'brokers');
    $roles->add_cap( 'edit_sinistri' ); 
    $roles->add_cap( 'edit_sinistris' ); 
    $roles->add_cap( 'edit_other_sinistris' ); 
    $roles->add_cap( 'publish_sinistris' ); 
    $roles->add_cap( 'read_sinistri' ); 
    $roles->add_cap( 'read_private_sinistris' ); 
    $roles->add_cap( 'delete_sinistri' ); 

    $admins = get_role( 'brokers','administrator' );
    $admins->add_cap( 'edit_area_clienti' ); 
    $admins->add_cap( 'edit_area_clientis' ); 
    $admins->add_cap( 'edit_other_area_clientis' ); 
    $admins->add_cap( 'publish_area_clientis' ); 
    $admins->add_cap( 'read_area_clienti' ); 
    $admins->add_cap( 'read_private_area_clientis' ); 
    $admins->add_cap( 'delete_area_clienti' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps');
```

But i've a problem. I can see the CPT only with brokers role and not also with administrator role. How can i see the two CPT with brokers and administrator roles? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$admins = get_role( 'brokers','administrator' );` part doesn't make sense.

`get_role()` only accepts one role name and only ever returns one role. You need to make these changes to the two roles separately.

Comment: Thnk's much. Now i have an other problem. Everyone can access on frontend at the post of custom post tye. I try to use the UAM plugin to setting private all post but i not have a result. How can i setting that only subscriber user can access and read the post of custom post type? (on frontend)?

Comment: I try to setup the post ad private post and add this code '$subrole = get_role( 'subscriber' );
// For private pages
$subrole->add_cap( 'read_private_area_clientis' );' but if i try to see the page ad subscriber i have a 404 error :(

Comment: @Federica please ask new question if you have one :) Comments aren't meant for such.